# ADO.Net synchronization services filter

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, synchronization, sql-server-ce

I have a VB.Net windows application in Visual Studio 2010 that I want to use ADO.Net synchronization services and only synchronize a subset of the data in each table. The main database with all of the data is in SQL Server 2008 R2, the LocalDataCache is using Compact SQL.   I have found several examples like:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726003(v=sql.100).aspx#Y1947   but they are very confusing.

If I have a table in SQL Server that has rows of data in it for several users, but I only want to see 1 user's data, I want to only synchronize this one users data.  The primary key of the table is a GUID, I want to set the Filter Criteria to be something like:   UserID = 'A34D81B5-EF3F-4B57-B795-F7F2D3B9DBA0'

I've looked at this and cannot get it to work for me:
[Sync Framework : Can I Sync only a subset of my tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385796/sync-framework-can-i-sync-only-a-subset-of-my-tables)

All of the examples I have found seem to be making this way more difficult than it seems like it should be.  Does anyone have a simple example of how to bidirectionally keep SQL CE in sync using a filter like this?

I have added the item:  Local Database Cache   and it works great if I want to synchronize the entire database to the Compact SQL, but I don't want all of the rows of data. I want all of the columns, but want to filter the rows that it keeps in sync.

None of the code snippets that I have found work end to end... they are all very vague and this is totally new to me.  I have never use Compact SQL before.

Thanks!